# Can someone play piano good without knowing how?

Tags: piano

Hey so my fingers just know wht keys to press and it sounds right but I don't know how to play like read keys and music sheets what can it be? Am I just talented?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Yes, loads of people play an instrument without knowing what they're doing. Some play with mediocrity, some play really well. The phenomenon is known but not explained. Talent maybe isn't the apposite word.

Comment: Did you get this ability all of a sudden, or did it develop gradually through playing and making sounds? I know a guitar player who can play in key if he just plays and doesn't think, but if he is given any sort of verbal of visual direction, any letter name, chord name, number, anything, everything gets completely messed up. He developed this skill by playing and listening. But reading, counting, thinking, remembering, following structures, no can do. I like playing with him because it's all about listening and making sounds. Any key is fine like Bb minor, if he just doesn't have to think.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this isn't surprising; many great performers have been self-taught. You might wonder how it's working; I'd suggest that it just means you're observant. Consciously or not, you're learning by trial and error which combinations "sound right."